# How to get role members count in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I want to get member count who have specific role. role.member is collection. how can i get member count? 
ps i'll use role id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `role.members.size`:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    let guild = await message.guild.fetchMembers();
    let roleID = '3933783737379';
    let memberCount = guild.roles.get(roleID).members.size;
    message.channel.send(memberCount + " members have this role!");
});
```

Note this only counts cached members so maybe you will have to use `guild.fetchMembers()` before.