# Role Count stats for Discord discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Im trying to add a Role Count stats for my Discord Server. Unfortunatley i only know how to count all members on the Discord and not a specific Role. My question is, how to change the script, so that it counts members in a  specific role and display them.

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
    await bot.channels.cache.get('880082719483232276' ).setName(`Total Member: ${member.guild.memberCount}`)
})

bot.on('guildMemberRemove', async (member) => {
    await  bot.channels.cache.get('880082719483232276' ).setName(`Total Member: ${member.guild.memberCount}`)
})
```

Comment: Do you mean how many members have a specific role?

Comment: Yeah, i want to count members in a specific Role and display them just like this: https://gyazo.com/2c9c38d3a9fa8bbf694e02261f3ab7c5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get role members count in discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992002/how-to-get-role-members-count-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been already asked by another user. Please refer to their post. ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992002/how-to-get-role-members-count-in-discord-js))

However you can use `role.members.size`:

```
const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get('GUILD ID');
const role = guild.roles.cache.get('ROLE ID');

bot.channels.cache.get('880082719483232276' ).setName(`Role Member Count: ${role.members.size}`)
```

Comment: Now it's giving me this Error: 

`PS C:\User\DiscordBot> node . 
C:\User\DiscordBot\index.js:63 const role = guild.roles.cache.get('878377313555873812'); ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined at Object.<anonymous> (C:\User\DiscordBot\index.js:63:20)`